# flash embed code closed

Tags: flash, embed

ok so i got a embed code which is hosted on another site 
i enter the script to my page but now it makes my html validation fail

with errors like this one

```
sh_id=cfe4b9038d67c69a9016a223b1040583&watermark=0&clickTag=null" width="1000"…
```

they all mainly apply to this part of it &watermark=0&clickTag=null"

and the validator says i need a /> but when i change it from > to /> dreamweaver says it invaid

```
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"><param name="wmode" value="transparent"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
```

i dont know this code is there away to change it and still work? i deleted it from the end but then the watermark appears again.

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing my doctype and add `&;` instead of just `&`.