# Whats the best way to embed a flash file from a link?

Tags: hyperlink, flash, embed, shockwave

I have looked around, but still have not found a very good answer to my question.

I would like to know how I can embed a flash game into my website Via HTML or Java in order for it to play.

I have the SWF file, but am unable to put the file on the site, so I got this link "https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/flight.swf?w=AAAYS8vwABuIJB3QbyhV1kSX778W0mXh4xRoQ0ADqm4w6g" that is JUST the flash game

Whats the best way to insert this into my site?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442039/flash-embed-code-closed

Comment: or of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948091/embedding-swf-files-on-an-html-page

Comment: Neither of those are duplicates :/ One is just about some watermark code and the other specifies the swf file in the site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a general script which will embed your flash movie in a html page, theres several ways to do this but below will work just copy and paste the code on to your html page in the body area.Check the adobe website if you need other parameters or more information.

```
<object id="yourmovie.swf" width="550" height="450" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0" align="middle" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="src" value="http://www.yourwebsite/yourmovie.swf" />
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="sameDomain" />
<param name="pluginspage" value="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
<embed id="slots.swf" width="476" height="321" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"src="http://www.yourwebsite/yourmovie.swf"
allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" quality="high" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" 
pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" align="middle" bgcolor="#ffffff" /> 
</object>
```

To use a link from java my option will be create a button/link thats open another window with the above on that html page